# Rails 4.0 param is missing or the value is empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters

I have an Opportunity model that has a nested resource Link. In my views/opportunities/show page when I click on "DestroY' for one of the links, I get the error:

param is missing or the value is empty: link

The code snippet it is complaining about is:

```
def link_params
     params.require(:link).permit(:description, :link_url)
end
```

Here is my destroy code:

```
def destroy
  @opportunity = Opportunity.find(params[:opportunity_id])
  @link = @opportunity.links.find(link_params)
  @link.destroy
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to links_url, notice: 'Link was successfully destroyed.' }
    format.json { head :no_content }
end
```

Comment: Show the code for your destroy link.

Comment: the params are normally only used to update attributes of model entities (except `params[:id]` to find the object). In the destroy actions, there are normally no object attributes sent from the client, so why do you use `link_params` in your destroy action?

Comment: i've updated with my destroy code @gwcoffey

Comment: because without it i get the error undefined local variable or method `links_url' @joni

Comment: please also show us how the params hash looks. Also, normally the `params.require` method is only used when a rails model gets updated with the params. When you are just picking out a value from the hash for searching, you dont need this, you can just do `parmas[:link][:description]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change this:

```
 @link = @opportunity.links.find(link_params)
```

To this:

```
 @link = @opportunity.links.find(params[:id])
```

You don't have a `link` in your params, you just have an `id` and an `opportunity_id`.

Also, you have this:

```
respond_to do |format|
   format.html { redirect_to links_url, notice: 'Link was successfully destroyed.' }
...
end
```

I'm guessing you have your `links` resource nested inside `opportunities`. So there is no `links_url`. You need to use, i.e., `opportunities_links_url(@opportunity)`.

Finally, note that you probably want `opportunities_links_path` rather than `opportunities_links_url` unless you explicitly need absolute URLs in this instance.

You can discover your link helper by running `rake routes`. Everything in the leftmost "prefix" column can be called with `_url` or `_path` on the end to generate a url.

Comment: I tried that and I got the error: undefined local variable or method `links_url' for the code snippet format.html { redirect_to links_url, notice: 'Link was successfully destroyed.' } @gwcoffey

Comment: revised to fix that as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error.
U must be using **before_action :link_params** at the top,
instead do this **before_action :link_params,only: [:create]**